# Generate excel file containing multiple sheets using PhpExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I am trying to generate Excel file with multiple worksheets in it, and the file is generating with proper data, but giving error while opening it.

error is as:
[image]

Also, when I am trying to iterate over sheets through loop, I unable to access sheets except sheet one.

**PHP error occured:**
 *You tried to set a sheet active by the out of bounds index: 1. The actual number of sheets is 1.*

Does that means the others sheets are not inserted while creating file.

Comment: Sheet ids are offset from 0

Comment: But without some idea of your code, how can we know for certain what you might be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ob_clean() before, php://output as (CORRECT):

```
ob_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

You may using like (WRONG):

```
  $objWriter->save('php://output');
ob_clean();
```